# MYSQL: group by and count issues

Tags: mysql

I've done research on this problem, but am having trouble finding a solution.

[image]

How can I get the output like this ?

[image]

Comment: please post what you have tired?

Comment: Please see [this article](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) on how to ask for homework help. Also, the [allowable topics policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states that "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: I've done research too

Answer (score 0):

You can join your original table to a subquery which tallies the students attending each school.

```
SELECT t1.student,
       t2.count,
       t1.school
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT school, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY school
) t2
    ON t1.school = t2.school
ORDER BY t2.count DESC,
         t1.school
```

Note that your intended order was not clear from the question.  You might have been looking for this ordering:

```
ORDER BY t1.school,
         t1.count    -- or t2.count DESC
```

Comment: thanx for your time sir ill try it :)

Comment: But this would include the `d` student row, and not double up the `h` student row... OP result shows students `a`, `e`, `h`, `h`,  Not `a`, `d`, `e`, `h`

Comment: @spencer7593 I'm guessing that is a typo, it doesn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: ahh sorry sir typo error :) but thanks a lot for your responce

Answer (score 0):

If you really want every student appears in rows, you should do it like this:

```
select
    yourtable.student, t.cnt as `count`, t.school
from (
    select count(id) as cnt, school
    from yourtable
    group by school
) t
left join yourtable
on yourtable.school = t.school
order by t.school, yourtable.id
```

or if you just want all the student for every school, you can use `group_concat`

```
select
    group_concat(student) as student,
    count(id) as `count`,
    school
from yourtable
group by school
```

the student will be separeted by `,` in one row for each school.

Comment: You don't need `LEFT JOIN` here because every school in the original table is guaranteed to appear in the subquery.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Right, maybe no need, but `left join` also works :-)

Comment: @ZEdmarSanchez Group by is enough as suggested by Forward. Good one Forward!